# Where Do Birds Go

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, humor

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

**Where do birds go?!** A famous ship?  A Channel Island?  A river in Greece?  A Caribbean island?  A conifer leaf?  A circle of light?  A California stadium?  A New York borough?  An Egyptian city?  Cyberspace?  A moon of Saturn?

> ANACTHEBPIEDLEALDYAINETBLYNROSEBGLIQUE

<sup>NB This is *not* a cipher puzzle.</sup>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First step

> Split up the string of letters as follows
>  AN
>  AC
>  THEB
>  PIEDLE
>  ALDY
>  A
>  INET
>  BLYN
>  ROSEB
>  GL
>  IQUE

Next step

> Notice that in each string we can insert the name of a bird to give an answer to one of the questions in the main body.
>  **TIT**AN
>  AC**HERON**
>  THE B**EAGLE**
>  PI**NE NE**EDLE
>  ALD**ERNE**Y
>  A**SWAN**
>  IN**TERN**ET
>  B**ROOK**LYN
>  ROSE B**OWL**
>  GL**ORIOLE**
>  **MARTIN**IQUE

Finally

> Reading down the first letter in each bird's name, we obtain the answer to the question "Where do birds go?!" which is
>  **THE NEST ROOM**

Ordering of the questions (as explained by Stiv)

> The questions are ordered alphabetically by the name of the bird inserted to get the answer.

Comment: You got it, well done :) (And yes, it's toilet humour - or perhaps t**OWLET** humour? ... Er, maybe not...)

Comment: @Stiv Maybe a t**OWLET**te?  Those might be found in the same location...

Comment: **HERON** these jokes makes me **SWAN**t to **ORIOLE** my eyes ;-).

Comment: I don't understand the ordering of the question-mark-marked noun phrases. cc @Stiv

Comment: @msh210 Alphabetical by what's inserted

Comment: Ah, I hadn't notice the ordering actually, will add in a comment.

Comment: Was just an extra way of assisting the solver in knowing they were on the right track :)

Comment: The puzzle must have a mistake then, because the ship should be 'titanic' not 'titan'

Comment: @paddotk No, the ship is the beagle, titan is the moon.

Comment: @hexomino Ah that explains it XD, thanks